Missing event columns for user_data?
I am sending standard and custom events to branch.io. Accorrding to this doc there should be user_data: screen_dpi, screen_height and screen_width. But it seems I can't pick those as event columns when viewing LiveView.

Are these data being logged?
Is there a way to view this data in branch dashboard?

EDIT_1: I was able to view screen_height and screen_width in exported csv, but still missing screen_dpi

That's probably to narrow of a question. You should try directing it to branch customer service.
